# Proguard function names ambiguity

Tags: android, proguard, deobfuscation

I need to know is there some option to prevent giving same name to different functions during obfuscation.

**Mapping file:**

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.BasicHttpCacheStorage -> org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.f:
    67:68:void putEntry(java.lang.String,org.apache.http.client.cache.HttpCacheEntry) -> a
    78:78:org.apache.http.client.cache.HttpCacheEntry getEntry(java.lang.String) -> a
```

I'd like to have different names for different functions instead of lines interval.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The option `-useuniqueclassmembernames` does this, at least for names that aren't overloaded to start with (java allows overloaded names as long as the argument types are different).