# What does <OR> means in Proguard deobfuscated trace?

Tags: proguard, android-proguard, deobfuscation

In my Playstore's, I noticed that the deobfuscated code contains quite amount of `<OR>` in the stack traces.

(Example `at <OR>.onAttach(ProfileLandingFragment.java)`).

What does the `<OR>` really means?

```
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.example.fragment.LandingFragment.newInstance(ProfileLandingFragment.java)
    at <OR>.onAttach(ProfileLandingFragment.java)
    at <OR>.onActivityResult(ProfileLandingFragment.java)
    at <OR>.onCreateView(ProfileLandingFragment.java)
    at <OR>.onViewCreated(ProfileLandingFragment.java)
    at <OR>.access$000(ProfileLandingFragment.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java)
    at <OR>.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java)
    at <OR>.onDetach(Fragment.java)
    at <OR>.onOptionsMenuClosed(Fragment.java)
    at <OR>.onContextItemSelected(Fragment.java)
    at <OR>.performCreateView(Fragment.java)
    at <OR>.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.modifiesAlpha(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.shouldRunOnHWLayer(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.throwException(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.beginTransaction(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.popBackStack(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.putFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.getFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dump(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.makeOpenCloseAnimation(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.makeFadeAnimation(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.loadAnimation(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.isStateAtLeast(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.removeFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.findFragmentByTag(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.allocBackStackIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.setBackStackIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.popBackStackState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.restoreAllState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.attachController(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchConfigurationChanged(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.modifiesAlpha(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.shouldRunOnHWLayer(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.throwException(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.beginTransaction(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.popBackStack(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.putFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.getFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dump(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.makeOpenCloseAnimation(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.makeFadeAnimation(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.loadAnimation(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.isStateAtLeast(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.removeFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.findFragmentByTag(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.allocBackStackIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.setBackStackIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.popBackStackState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.restoreAllState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.attachController(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchConfigurationChanged(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.hideFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.findFragmentById(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.findFragmentByWho(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.addBackStackState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.dispatchOptionsMenuClosed(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at <OR>.transitToStyleIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java)
    at <OR>.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.addOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.distanceInfluenceForSnapDuration(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.smoothScrollTo(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.addNewItem(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.populate(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.calculatePageOffsets(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.infoForChild(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.recomputeScrollPosition(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.onPageScrolled(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.completeScroll(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.isGutterDrag(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.determineTargetPage(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.onSecondaryPointerUp(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.canScroll(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.executeKeyEvent(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.getChildRectInPagerCoordinates(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.access$000(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.access$200(ViewPager.java)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.isDecorView(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.requestParentDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java)
    at <OR>.arrowScroll(ViewPager.java)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Proguard will often re-use method names which means when it comes to de-obfuscation the map cannot tell the difference, so it has to show you all the possibilities. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861986/how-do-you-interpret-a-deobfuscated-android-crash-report) and [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008613/proguard-function-names-ambiguity) might help.